# What's the best way to deploy a meteor-app?

Tags: meteor, hosting, web-deployment

There are a few kind of types to deploying a meteor-app. For example I found a third-party tool (meteor galaxy).

Is it usefully to use it or should I deploy it directly to a registered domain?
What´s the pros and cons?

What´s the best (or correct) way to deploy it?

And what do I have to keep in mind?
 mongoDB is not neccessary for this app. It'll run on SSL at a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty broad, and will attract opinionated answers, so is likely to be closed.

There is a tool called Meteor Up (mup) which will allow you to deploy to a server such as AWS EC2 or Digital Ocean. It makes use of docker containers, so it works simply and quickly.

Galaxy is probably a bit more up market, as it is designed to be a scalable solution specifically built for Meteor. It costs a bit more, and I think you still need to host your database elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in past and I now deploy on Heroku, it recognizes as node.js application but there will be no problem as such.

[This](https://medium.com/nona-web/deploying-and-hosting-meteor-on-heroku-mongolab-for-free-37050a3ebd7e) is the post which helped me. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Meteor.js and Heroku toolbelt

   For Mac:

   ```
   curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
   ```

   For Windows:

   ```
   Meteor installer
   ```

   Heroku: Heroku Toolbelt
2. Create your Meteor application

   ```
   meteor create foobar
   cd foobar
   ```
3. Initialize the directory as a git managed repository

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "My first commit!"
   ```
4. Create your Heroku instance

   ```
   heroku login 
   heroku apps:create foobar
   ```
5. Set a Meteor buildpack for your Heroku instance

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
   ```
6. Create a new mLab* instance

   ```
   heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox
   ```
7. Get your MongoLab URI

   ```
   heroku config | grep MONGODB_URI
   ```

// Alternatively, run "heroku config" to display all your configuration variables, but truthfully we only need the MONGODB_URI

// Be careful of running "heroku config" and leaving your console in the open since it displays all your important environment variables like Stripe API keys

8. Set the configurations of your Meteor app running on Heroku

   ```
   heroku config:add MONGO_URL=<MONGODB_URI value>
   heroku config:add ROOT_URL=https://foobar.herokuapp.com
   ```
9. Check your remotes to ensure heroku is there

   ```
   git remote -v
   ```
10. Deploy the app

    ```
    git push heroku master
    ```